# Define jQuery "eq"

Tags: jquery

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around the [jQuery eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq). Can someone explain its use to me? What and how does it index?

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Mario</li>
    <li>Luigi</li>
    <li>Princess</li>
    <li>Toad</li>
</ul>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
alert($("ul li").eq(0).text()); // Mario
alert($("ul li").eq(1).text()); // Luigi
alert($("ul li").eq(2).text()); // Princess
alert($("ul li").eq(3).text()); // Toad
```

Answer (score 9):

`.eq(i)` returns an element from a collection at a specified index `i`.

In the example from the link you posted:

`$("p").eq(1).css("color", "red")`

It basically says: "Find all elements that match $("p") then take the 2nd one and change its color to red."

`$("p")` matches all `<p>` elements in your document.  You now have a collection of those.

`$("p").eq(1)` reduces this collection to the 2nd element only.

the `.css("color", "red")` part simply operates on that element to change its color to red.

Comment: Important to note that eq() returns a jQuery object containing the element at the specified index.  This is in contrast to [] or get(), which return plain dom elements.

Answer (score 4):

To understand how [`eq()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq) works, I think it helps to understand how [`$()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) works in jQuery. When you specify

```
$([selector],[context])

//which is the same as

$([context]).find([selector])
```

what gets returned is a ***jQuery*** object (sometimes referred to as a *wrapped set*) which, amongst other properties, has a property starting with `0` and incrementing by 1 for each element that matches the selector. A `length` property is also set, which is why the matched elements of a jQuery object can be iterated over like an array (using a for loop or commands such as [`each([callback])`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback)).

Let's now have a look at the source for `eq()`

```
 eq: function( i ) {
  return this.slice( i, +i + 1 );
 },
```

we see that `eq()` is achieved using the [`slice()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) command of the jQuery object, so let's also have a look at that

```
 slice: function() {
  return this.pushStack( Array.prototype.slice.apply( this, arguments ),
   "slice", Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(",") );
 },
```

and also need to look at `pushStack()`, a command used quite a bit internally

```
 // Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
 // (returning the new matched element set)
 pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
  // Build a new jQuery matched element set
  var ret = jQuery( elems );

  // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
  ret.prevObject = this;

  ret.context = this.context;

  if ( name === "find" )
   ret.selector = this.selector + (this.selector ? " " : "") + selector;
  else if ( name )
   ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";

  // Return the newly-formed element set
  return ret;
 },
```

we can see that `pushStack` takes an array and returns a new jQuery object. The elements that form the matched elements of the new jQuery object are obtained by calling [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) on the JavaScript Array [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function and passing the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) of the jQuery slice function in as the `argsArray`.

The [`get()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) command on the other hand is more straightforward. Let's have a look at the source

```
 // Get the Nth element in the matched element set OR
 // Get the whole matched element set as a clean array
 get: function( num ) {
  return num === undefined ?

   // Return a 'clean' array
   Array.prototype.slice.call( this ) :

   // Return just the object
   this[ num ];
 }
```

called without an argument for the `num` parameter, the jQuery object is converted to an array, using [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on the JavaScript Array [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function. If `num` is defined, then the value held in the corresponding property of the jQuery object is returned, much the same as the following

```
$([selector]).get(0)

//is the same as

$([selector])[0]
```

Comment: +1 for the hard work of explaining jQuery through its source. Really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the example from docs:

```
$("p").eq(1).css("color", "red")

$("p")                selects all paragraphs in your document
.eq(1)                selects the second element only
.css("color", "red")  applies css rule to the selected element
```

Comment: It seems like `.eq()` would've been called `.get()` if that wasn't already taken. `.get()` grabs the underlying DOM element. Maybe `$($("p").get(1))` is the same as `$("p").eq(1)`

Comment: it is. I think the only down side of `$($("p").get(1))` syntax is that it's not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be getting caught up on the word 'index'.

In this case, 'index' refers to a specific item in a collection of items.  So **eq** will give you access to a single item within a matched set of elements.