# how to find a td by index in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can i change the inner html by getting element by index
i want to change the content of cells according to their index values

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
function LFLS() {
    // LFLS => load from local Storage
    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);//it return values like ("1,2","2,5", etc.)
        console.log(key)
        row = key.split(",")[0];
        col = key.split(",")[1];
//how to get the cell by row and col
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look this may help you, [jQuery eq()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428438/define-jquery-eq)

Answer (score 2):

As Sakil said you can use eq(). Try this:

```js
function LFLS() {
    // load from local Storage
    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        row = key.split(",")[0];
        col = key.split(",")[1];
        // how to get the cell by row and col
        $("table tr").eq(row).children().eq(col).html('NEW VALUE')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the following snippets.

Before your for loop

```
const rows = $("table tr");
```

After you obtain row & col variables

```
const cellToUpdate = rows[row].children[col];
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to programatically loop through the table you could use the following snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const rows = $("table tr");
    for( i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
        const currRow = rows[i];
        const rowChildren = currRow.children;
        for( n = 0; n < rowChildren.length; n++ ) {
            const cell = rowChildren[n];
            cell.innerHTML = "My new data for row: " + i + " in cell " + n;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: bro its overly confusing + the solution above is better and simple

Answer (score 0):

Is something on the lines of below not going to work for you for some reason?

$("table tr:nth-of-type([your-row])).eq([your-col]).html([your_content]);